# Mink doesn't work with behat 3.0.12

Tags: symfony, behat, mink

I installed Behat, Mink and a few other related packages. Here is my composer.json file:

```
  "require":{
    //...
    "behat/behat": "~3.0.6",
    "behat/symfony2-extension": "dev-master",
    "behat/mink": "dev-master",
    "behat/mink-browserkit-driver": "dev-master",
    "behat/mink-goutte-driver": "dev-master",
    "behat/mink-selenium2-driver": "dev-master",
    "phpunit/php-code-coverage": "dev-master",
    "phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects": "dev-master",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "dev-master"
   }
```

And here is my behat.yml file:

```
default:
  extensions:
    Behat\Symfony2Extension:
      mink_driver: true
      kernel:
        env: test
        debug: true
    Behat\MinkExtension\Extension:
        base_url: 'http://localhost/app_test.php/'
        #javascript_session: sahi
        browser_name: chrome
        sahi:
        goutte: ~
        selenium2: ~
paths:
    features: features
    bootstrap: %behat.paths.features%/Context
```

Now when I run behat I get following error:
**[Behat\Testwork\ServiceContainer\Exception\ExtensionInitializationException]

`Behat\MinkExtension\Extension` extension file or class could not be located.**

Does anyone know how to fix this?
Thanks in advance.

**SOLVED:**

I simply forgot to add this line:

```
"require": {
//...
"behat/mink-extension": "dev-master",
//... }
```

and in your behat.yml:
comment this:

```
# mink_driver: true
```

and change this:

```
Behat\MinkExtension\Extension:
```

to this:

```
Behat\MinkExtension:
```

Comment: "change this: `Behat\MinkExtension\Extension:` to this: `Behat\MinkExtension:`"

This saved me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

FYI you don't need `"behat/mink-extension": "dev-master"` any more.

It works for me with:

```
"behat/behat": "3.*@stable",
"behat/mink": "1.6.*@stable",
"behat/mink-extension": "@stable",
"behat/mink-goutte-driver": "@stable",
```

Comment: Instead all 4 use just last 2. It will install required dependency: `mink` and `behat` desired versions

Comment: But you hide a dependency and rely on transitional dependency to load behat and mink. I am not a fan of such approach.

Comment: You are right. I stick with this one liner because I experienced conflicts of version in Behat extensions causing abort of installation.