# behat minkextension selenium - extension file or class could not be located

Tags: php, selenium, behat, mink

Hoping someone can help with this - I'm using Windows, not Mac. Self teaching, so don't have an expert to ask.

Got everything installed and I'm able to test .feature files using a php calculator (if I press 50 and then etc.)

I'd like to use it to test websites for fun.
My folder structure is:
C:\Behat\features
C:\Behat\vendor (where everything downloads to)
C:\Behat\behat.yml
C:\Behat\composer.json & .lock

Composer.json contains

```
"require": {
    "php":          ">=5.3.2",
    "behat/behat":  "~3.0,>=3.0.5",
    "behat/mink":   "~1.5",
    "symfony/config": "~2.2",
    "behat/mink-extension": "*",
    "behat/mink-goutte-driver": "*",
    "behat/mink-selenium2-driver": "*"
},

"require-dev": {
    "phpspec/phpspec":          "~2.0",
    "behat/mink-goutte-driver": "~1.1@dev"
},

"autoload": {
    "psr-0": { "Behat\\MinkExtension": "src/" }
},
```

The behat.yml file contains (one attempt)

```
default:
paths:
features: features
bootstrap: %behat.paths.features%/bootstrap
extensions:
Behat\MinkExtension:
  goutte: ~
  selenium2: ~
```

Another attempt

```
default:
suites:
my_suite:
  contexts:
    - FeatureContext
    - Behat\MinkExtension\Context\MinkContext
extensions:
Behat\MinkExtension:
  base_url:  'http://example.com'
  sessions:
    default:
      goutte: ~
```

Added "use Behat\MinkExtension\Context\MinkContext;" to the FeatureContext.php file
Also added the C:\Behat\vendor\bin to my PATH

But I always get this message when running behat

```
[Behat\Testwork\ServiceContainer\Exception\ExtensionInitializationException]
`Behat\MinkExtension` extension file or class could not be located.
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Websites that have helped others, but don't fix for me
[stackoverflow question but they were missing the require](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25049234/mink-doesnt-work-with-behat-3-0-12)

[Not the same extension but didn't help with my .yml file](https://github.com/laracasts/Behat-Laravel-Extension-Example-App/issues/1)

[An old guide that didn't work for me either](http://lin-clark.com/blog/2013/11/26/quickstart-testing-with-behat-mink-selenium/)

Comment: The autoload setting says that the Mink Extension sources are to be found in `C:\Behat\src` which is probably not the case. Was this generated by Composer?

Comment: @b263 You megastar! It wasn't generated by composer - I think it was an example one. I changed it to ` "autoload": { "psr-0": { "Behat\\MinkExtension": "vendor/behat/mink-extension/src/" } }, ` and it is working as expected now!